# How to readlines() from urllib

Tags: python, http, urllib

I have program using http and I want to read data from http:

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen(someAddress).read()
```

And prepare from it list of lines like returning lines by readlines() method for file.

How to do it?

Comment: You could have easily tried this yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`urlopen()` returns an object that acts just like a file, and supports `.readlines()`:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(someAddress)

lines = response.readlines():
```

It also supports iteration:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(someAddress)

for line in response:
```

You already called `.read()` on the response object; you could also just call `str.splitlines()` on that:

```
lines = data.splitlines(True)
```

where `True` tells `str.splitlines()` to preserve line endings.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do something like. I use urllib2, but it shouldn't be so different:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

def getPage(link, splitting = '\n'):
    request = Request(link)
    try:
        response = urlopen(request)
    except IOError:
        return -1
    else:
        the_page = response.read()
        return the_page.split(splitting)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for what I wanted to do, which is to have all the lines in a list form.