# Creating an array in Python from a web stream

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'm just starting out with python 2.7 and trying to perform a rather basic data manipulation task.

Objective: pull a list from a website and manipulate the data line by line.

However I am falling at the second hurdle; putting the data in to an array that can later be manipulated.

I have tried several methods and instead of processing each array entry per line it is instead processing an array entry per character. Here's are the methods I have so far tried:

```
import urllib2, numpy 
from array import array
listraw = urllib2.urlopen("https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php?download=badips").read()
list = [line.rstrip('\n\r') for line in listraw]
array = []
for line in listraw:
    array.append(line)
numpyarray = numpy.asarray(listraw)

lines = tuple(listraw)
#print r'Listraw:'
#print listraw
print 'Single List item: '
print list [10]
print array[10]
print lines[10]
print numpyarray[10]
```

Output:

```
Single List item: 
#
#
#
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print numpyarray[10]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I have tried both `\n` and `\r` solo in the list variable with no success. If I uncomment the `print listraw` it shows the entire list with carriage returns in the correct locations.

I know I am missing something basic because `array2= ["bob","bert","geof"]` works, but everything I have found to date has not solved my problem. What is the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: `response.read()` returns a single string. So you'd need to either `split()` that string yourself at newlines, or use `response.readlines()`. See this question for more details: [How to readlines() from urllib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131227/how-to-readlines-from-urllib)

Comment: `Readlines` was the most efficient way of achieving my goal. Thanks for the lesson; I'm slowly becoming familiar with Python syntax. If you could add an answer to such effect I could mark it as the resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Looping at the data, you seem to be confusing `strip` and `split`. Try:

```
data_list = listraw.split('\n')
```

Also, if you notice, I renamed `list` to `data_list`, since, `list` is a python builtin, and assigning it something overrides it, which could lead to unexpected and difficult to trace bugs in future.

Also, based on @Lukas' comment, you could refactor the code as:

```
listraw = urllib2.urlopen("https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php?download=badips")
array = []
for line in listraw:
    array.append(line.strip())
numpyarray = numpy.asarray(listraw)
```

Comment: That will still loop over every *character* in `listraw`, and attempt to split it.

Comment: @LukasGraf Ah, yes, I realized and was just fixing it. You beat me to it :)

Comment: The `split('')` is still not right though

Comment: And just `split()` will split at *all* whitespace, including spaces. I highly recommend testing your code before posting it as an answer ;-)

Comment: @LukasGraf yes true, fixed.

Comment: Brain freeze! Yes, I confused strip for split... as soon as I changed that it all worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.loadtxt`, it will handle the empty lines and the lines starting with `#`:

```
import urllib2, numpy

listraw = urllib2.urlopen("https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php?download=badips")

print(numpy.loadtxt(listraw, dtype=str))
```

Which will give you:

```
['101.0.89.3' '101.200.81.187' '103.19.89.118' '103.230.84.239'
 '103.241.0.100' '103.26.128.84' '103.4.52.150' '103.7.59.135'
 '107.179.62.12' '108.174.157.123' '109.127.8.242' '109.229.210.250'
 '109.229.36.65' '113.29.230.24' '116.193.77.118' '120.25.63.2'
 '120.31.134.133' '120.63.157.195' '123.30.129.179' '124.110.195.160'
 '128.210.157.251' '141.105.71.73' '151.97.190.239' '157.7.170.62'
 '158.69.114.173' '160.97.52.229' '162.223.94.56' '175.107.192.78'
 '177.4.23.159' '180.182.234.200' '185.24.234.108' '185.25.117.49'
 '185.25.119.84' '185.25.49.241' '185.80.129.62' '186.64.120.104'
 '187.174.252.247' '188.219.154.228' '188.226.141.142' '188.241.140.212'
 '188.241.140.222' '188.241.140.224' '188.247.135.53' '188.247.135.58'
 '188.247.135.74' '188.247.135.99' '190.123.35.140' '190.123.35.141'
 '190.128.29.1' '190.15.192.25' '192.64.11.244' '192.99.148.26'
 '192.99.19.4' '193.0.200.185' '193.107.17.145' '193.107.17.55'
 '193.107.17.56' '193.107.19.24' '193.107.19.244' '193.146.210.69'
 '193.189.117.56' '193.201.227.142' '194.15.112.29' '194.15.112.30'
 '194.58.103.199' '195.20.40.123' '195.20.41.233' '195.20.42.1'
 '195.20.43.189' '195.20.44.100' '195.20.44.109' '195.20.46.116'
 '195.20.47.56' '195.242.161.117' '198.245.202.92' '199.115.228.68'
 '199.187.129.193' '199.201.121.185' '199.7.234.100' '201.149.83.183'
 '202.144.144.195' '202.29.22.38' '202.29.230.198' '202.67.13.107'
 '203.170.193.23' '209.164.84.70' '210.211.108.215' '210.4.76.221'
 '212.44.64.202' '213.147.67.20' '216.176.100.240' '216.176.184.21'
 '216.215.112.149' '222.29.197.232' '31.28.27.17' '31.7.63.146'
 '37.123.99.188' '37.143.11.189' '37.46.134.60' '37.48.108.162'
 '37.48.125.119' '46.151.52.191' '46.151.52.61' '46.151.54.46'
 '46.4.150.111' '58.195.1.4' '59.157.4.2' '60.13.186.5' '60.241.184.209'
 '63.249.152.74' '64.127.71.73' '64.182.215.68' '64.182.6.61' '64.85.233.8'
 '64.90.187.131' '78.138.104.167' '78.46.222.241' '80.65.93.241'
 '83.15.254.242' '83.212.117.233' '83.222.14.207' '83.69.233.121'
 '87.236.210.110' '87.236.210.124' '87.237.198.245' '87.246.143.242'
 '87.254.167.37' '89.40.181.101' '91.108.176.118' '91.236.213.74'
 '91.236.75.11' '92.53.119.248' '92.53.124.62' '93.171.205.12'
 '93.171.205.5' '94.103.36.55' '95.211.153.134' '98.131.185.136']
```

Appending each line and stripping is going to include the lines at the start:

```
#############################################################################################
# abuse.ch ZeuS IP blocklist "BadIPs" (excluding hijacked sites and free hosting providers) #
#                                                                                           #
# For questions please refer to https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php                  #
#############################################################################################
```

Which I imagine you don't want.

Comment: Not too familiar with the `urllib2` API any more, but doesn't `urlopen()` already return a file-like stream? So `StringIO(listraw.read())` is kind of unnecessary, isn't it?

Comment: @LukasGraf, yep,  added the wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, checking for the IPs is rather crude here: if a line starts with a digit, it is assumed to be an IP address ;)

```
import requests

url = 'https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php'
payload = {'download' : 'badips'}

res = requests.get(url, payload)

# ignore all empty lines and those that don't start with a number
bad_ips = [item for item in res.text.split('\n') if item and item[0].isdigit()]
```